# Detect interface promiscuous mode in my network

Tags: 12.04, networking, python, security

How can I detect and get the name or MAC address or IP address of any device in my network where the mode of its interface is promiscuous using a Python script.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty unclear question.

You can see if a PC is in **promiscuous** mode on a LAN, go here: [How to find out that a NIC is in promiscuous mode on a LAN?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3630/how-to-find-out-that-a-nic-is-in-promiscuous-mode-on-a-lan)

If you're trying to get in promiscuous mode using python on Linux try this:  [Python Sockets: Enabling Promiscuous Mode in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067405/python-sockets-enabling-promiscuous-mode-in-linux)

Other than that if you're trying to find an IP/MAC address, PC name, etc. through a LAN even if a user is in promiscuous mode, then I'd have to look more into it, otherwise trying asking or looking around on Stack Overflow.